# Why is TableSorter plugin not displaying results according to input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Tablesorter plugin with bootstrap 3. I have the tablesorter in my page. However, when I type in the input in search-box, the expected row doesnt get shown.

Here is my code-

```html
<head>
  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.25.0/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.25.0/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

  // NOTE: $.tablesorter.theme.bootstrap is ALREADY INCLUDED in the jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js
  // file; it is included here to show how you can modify the default classes
  $.tablesorter.themes.bootstrap = {
    // these classes are added to the table. To see other table classes available,
    // look here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables
    table        : 'table table-bordered table-striped',
    caption      : 'caption',
    // header class names
    header       : 'bootstrap-header', // give the header a gradient background (theme.bootstrap_2.css)
    sortNone     : '',
    sortAsc      : '',
    sortDesc     : '',
    active       : '', // applied when column is sorted
    hover        : '', // custom css required - a defined bootstrap style may not override other classes
    // icon class names
    icons        : '', // add "icon-white" to make them white; this icon class is added to the <i> in the header
    iconSortNone : 'bootstrap-icon-unsorted', // class name added to icon when column is not sorted
    iconSortAsc  : 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up', // class name added to icon when column has ascending sort
    iconSortDesc : 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down', // class name added to icon when column has descending sort
    filterRow    : '', // filter row class; use widgetOptions.filter_cssFilter for the input/select element
    footerRow    : '',
    footerCells  : '',
    even         : '', // even row zebra striping
    odd          : ''  // odd row zebra striping
  };

  // call the tablesorter plugin and apply the uitheme widget
  $("table").tablesorter({
    // this will apply the bootstrap theme if "uitheme" widget is included
    // the widgetOptions.uitheme is no longer required to be set
    theme : "bootstrap",

    widthFixed: true,

    headerTemplate : '{content} {icon}', // new in v2.7. Needed to add the bootstrap icon!

    // widget code contained in the jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js file
    // use the zebra stripe widget if you plan on hiding any rows (filter widget)
    widgets : [ "uitheme", "filter", "zebra" ],

    widgetOptions : {
      // using the default zebra striping class name, so it actually isn't included in the theme variable above
      // this is ONLY needed for bootstrap theming if you are using the filter widget, because rows are hidden
      zebra : ["even", "odd"],

      // reset filters button
      filter_reset : ".reset",

      // extra css class name (string or array) added to the filter element (input or select)
      filter_cssFilter: "form-control",

      // set the uitheme widget to use the bootstrap theme class names
      // this is no longer required, if theme is set
      // ,uitheme : "bootstrap"

    }
  })
  .tablesorterPager({

    // target the pager markup - see the HTML block below
    container: $(".ts-pager"),

    // target the pager page select dropdown - choose a page
    cssGoto  : ".pagenum",

    // remove rows from the table to speed up the sort of large tables.
    // setting this to false, only hides the non-visible rows; needed if you plan to add/remove rows with the pager enabled.
    removeRows: false,

    // output string - default is '{page}/{totalPages}';
    // possible variables: {page}, {totalPages}, {filteredPages}, {startRow}, {endRow}, {filteredRows} and {totalRows}
    output: '{startRow} - {endRow} / {filteredRows} ({totalRows})'

  });

});

</script>
</head>

<body>
  
  <table class="tablesorter tablesorter-bootstrap table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Profile id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Surname</th>
    <th class="filter-select filter-exact" data-placeholder="Select gender">Gender<th>
    <th class="filter-select filter-exact" data-placeholder="Select status">Active/ Inactive<th>
    <th>Transaction ID</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>

  <tfoot>
   <tr>
    <th>Profile id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Surname</th>
    <th>Gender<th>
    <th>Active/ Inactive<th>
    <th>Transaction ID</th>
   </tr>
<tr>
  <th colspan="7" class="ts-pager form-horizontal">
    <button type="button" class="btn first"><i class="icon-step-backward glyphicon glyphicon-step-backward"></i></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn prev"><i class="icon-arrow-left glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></i></button>
    <span class="pagedisplay"></span> <!-- this can be any element, including an input -->
    <button type="button" class="btn next"><i class="icon-arrow-right glyphicon glyphicon-forward"></i></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn last"><i class="icon-step-forward glyphicon glyphicon-step-forward"></i></button>

    <select class="pagesize input-mini" title="Select page size">
      <option selected="selected" value="10">10</option>
      <option value="20">20</option>
      <option value="30">30</option>
      <option value="40">40</option>
    </select>
    <select class="pagenum input-mini" title="Select page number">
      <option selected="selected" value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
  </th>
          </tr>
    </tfoot>  
  
  <tbody>
    
    
     <tr><td>Student01</td><td>Languages</td><td>male</td><td>80</td><td>70</td><td>75</td><td>80</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Student02</td><td>Mathematics</td><td>male</td><td>90</td><td>88</td><td>100</td><td>90</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Student03</td><td>Languages</td><td>female</td><td>85</td><td>95</td><td>80</td><td>85</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Student04</td><td>Languages</td><td>male</td><td>60</td><td>55</td><td>100</td><td>100</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Student05</td><td>Languages</td><td>female</td><td>68</td><td>80</td><td>95</td><td>80</td></tr>
    
</tbody>  
  
</body>
```

The problem is an extra blank column is getting added after column containing select-box preference. Also, it is not showing the results dynamically when I enter the input.

I took reference from here. [Tablesorter reference](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-bootstrap-theme.html)

I want to make my table just like that. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very dumb mistake. Don't get serious. You have used `<th>` and `<th>` for the closing tag also:

```
<tr>
  <th>Profile id</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Surname</th>
  <th class="filter-select filter-exact" data-placeholder="Select gender">Gender<th> <!-- this one -->
  <th class="filter-select filter-exact" data-placeholder="Select status">Active/ Inactive<th> <!-- this one -->
  <th>Transaction ID</th>
</tr>
```

I was able to get till this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.25.0/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.25.0/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $(function() {

    // NOTE: $.tablesorter.theme.bootstrap is ALREADY INCLUDED in the jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js
    // file; it is included here to show how you can modify the default classes
    $.tablesorter.themes.bootstrap = {
      // these classes are added to the table. To see other table classes available,
      // look here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables
      table        : 'table table-bordered table-striped',
      caption      : 'caption',
      // header class names
      header       : 'bootstrap-header', // give the header a gradient background (theme.bootstrap_2.css)
      sortNone     : '',
      sortAsc      : '',
      sortDesc     : '',
      active       : '', // applied when column is sorted
      hover        : '', // custom css required - a defined bootstrap style may not override other classes
      // icon class names
      icons        : '', // add "icon-white" to make them white; this icon class is added to the <i> in the header
      iconSortNone : 'bootstrap-icon-unsorted', // class name added to icon when column is not sorted
      iconSortAsc  : 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up', // class name added to icon when column has ascending sort
      iconSortDesc : 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down', // class name added to icon when column has descending sort
      filterRow    : '', // filter row class; use widgetOptions.filter_cssFilter for the input/select element
      footerRow    : '',
      footerCells  : '',
      even         : '', // even row zebra striping
      odd          : ''  // odd row zebra striping
    };

    // call the tablesorter plugin and apply the uitheme widget
    $("table").tablesorter({
      // this will apply the bootstrap theme if "uitheme" widget is included
      // the widgetOptions.uitheme is no longer required to be set
      theme : "bootstrap",

      widthFixed: true,

      headerTemplate : '{content} {icon}', // new in v2.7. Needed to add the bootstrap icon!

      // widget code contained in the jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js file
      // use the zebra stripe widget if you plan on hiding any rows (filter widget)
      widgets : [ "uitheme", "filter", "zebra" ],

      widgetOptions : {
        // using the default zebra striping class name, so it actually isn't included in the theme variable above
        // this is ONLY needed for bootstrap theming if you are using the filter widget, because rows are hidden
        zebra : ["even", "odd"],

        // reset filters button
        filter_reset : ".reset",

        // extra css class name (string or array) added to the filter element (input or select)
        filter_cssFilter: "form-control",

        // set the uitheme widget to use the bootstrap theme class names
        // this is no longer required, if theme is set
        // ,uitheme : "bootstrap"

      }
    })
    .tablesorterPager({

      // target the pager markup - see the HTML block below
      container: $(".ts-pager"),

      // target the pager page select dropdown - choose a page
      cssGoto  : ".pagenum",

      // remove rows from the table to speed up the sort of large tables.
      // setting this to false, only hides the non-visible rows; needed if you plan to add/remove rows with the pager enabled.
      removeRows: false,

      // output string - default is '{page}/{totalPages}';
      // possible variables: {page}, {totalPages}, {filteredPages}, {startRow}, {endRow}, {filteredRows} and {totalRows}
      output: '{startRow} - {endRow} / {filteredRows} ({totalRows})'

    });

  });

</script>

<table class="tablesorter tablesorter-bootstrap table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Profile id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Surname</th>
      <th class="filter-select filter-exact" data-placeholder="Select gender">Gender</th>
      <th class="filter-select filter-exact" data-placeholder="Select status">Active/ Inactive</th>
      <th>Transaction ID</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Profile id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Surname</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
      <th>Active/ Inactive</th>
      <th>Transaction ID</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="7" class="ts-pager form-horizontal">
        <button type="button" class="btn first"><i class="icon-step-backward glyphicon glyphicon-step-backward"></i></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn prev"><i class="icon-arrow-left glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></i></button>
        <span class="pagedisplay"></span> <!-- this can be any element, including an input -->
        <button type="button" class="btn next"><i class="icon-arrow-right glyphicon glyphicon-forward"></i></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn last"><i class="icon-step-forward glyphicon glyphicon-step-forward"></i></button>

        <select class="pagesize input-mini" title="Select page size">
          <option selected="selected" value="10">10</option>
          <option value="20">20</option>
          <option value="30">30</option>
          <option value="40">40</option>
        </select>
        <select class="pagenum input-mini" title="Select page number">
          <option selected="selected" value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>  

  <tbody>

    <tr><td>Student01</td><td>Languages</td><td>male</td><td>80</td><td>70</td><td>75</td><td>80</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Student02</td><td>Mathematics</td><td>male</td><td>90</td><td>88</td><td>100</td><td>90</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Student03</td><td>Languages</td><td>female</td><td>85</td><td>95</td><td>80</td><td>85</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Student04</td><td>Languages</td><td>male</td><td>60</td><td>55</td><td>100</td><td>100</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Student05</td><td>Languages</td><td>female</td><td>68</td><td>80</td><td>95</td><td>80</td></tr>
  </tbody>
```

**Something Working**

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI';}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
    $(".datatable").DataTable();
  });
</script>
<table class="datatable table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Profile id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Surname</th>
      <th class="filter-select filter-exact" data-placeholder="Select gender">Gender</th>
      <th class="filter-select filter-exact" data-placeholder="Select status">Active/ Inactive</th>
      <th>Transaction ID</th>
      <th>Some Mark</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Profile id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Surname</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
      <th>Active/ Inactive</th>
      <th>Transaction ID</th>
      <th>Some Mark</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>  

  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Student01</td><td>Languages</td><td>male</td><td>80</td><td>70</td><td>75</td><td>80</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Student02</td><td>Mathematics</td><td>male</td><td>90</td><td>88</td><td>100</td><td>90</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Student03</td><td>Languages</td><td>female</td><td>85</td><td>95</td><td>80</td><td>85</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Student04</td><td>Languages</td><td>male</td><td>60</td><td>55</td><td>100</td><td>100</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Student05</td><td>Languages</td><td>female</td><td>68</td><td>80</td><td>95</td><td>80</td></tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: The other part is.. if  you go through the link; they have a search filter. I was asking for that. I resolved this one already yesterday.

Comment: Yes Datatable makes it work. I was trying to do it using tablesorter2. Its acceptable.

Comment: @Nevermore Lemme know if you are waiting for something else from this, as this has got all the features you want, from pagination, sorting, to filters. `:)`

Comment: I want to bring one thing into your notice that the controls in the header dont show up in Mozilla. However, they do show up nicely in Chrome. What might be the trouble.. any guesses?

Comment: @Nevermore aha... Lemme check.

Comment: Its showing up now. It appears to me like the bootstrap files didnt loadup in time. Thanks for the intimation Praveen. :-)

Comment: @Nevermore I just earned the trust you had on me. `:)` I am happy. `:D`

Comment: Glad to hear that; Praveen. :-)