# Why is this jQuery validate working wrongly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two email fields: email1 & email2. I want both of them to be distinct. For some reasons, I am keeping email1 as readonly and email2 as editable. Below is my code-

My custom validator is as follows -

```
$.validator.addMethod("email_not_same", function(value, element) {
  return $('#email1').val() != $('#email2').val();
}, "Both emails should not be same");
```

My rules are as follows -

```
 email1: {
    required: true,
    email: true,
  },
  email2: {
    email: true,
    email_not_same: true,
  },
```

My html code is as follows:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label><strong>Emails : </strong></label>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <input class="form-control" name="email1" placeholder="Email 1" type="email">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <input class="form-control" name="email2" placeholder="Email 2" type="email">
</div>
```

When I enter both email addresses same; it shows the message according to my rule. However, after that when I change my email2, it still shows the error message. Please help.

Comment: I notice no `data-val-email-not-same` attribute on the 2nd input. This intended ?

Comment: @Krohn Yes its intended. I want email2 to be distinct from email1. Hence I did it like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `id` attribute for the emails:

```
<input class="form-control" id="email1" name="email1" placeholder="Email 1" type="email" />
<input class="form-control" id="email2" name="email2" placeholder="Email 2" type="email" />
```

But you are using them here:

```
return $('#email1').val() != $('#email2').val();
```

Comment: I dont belive I made that mistake!! T_T

Comment: Hi Praveen.. Can you please have a look at this one too ..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34618703/why-is-tablesorter-plugin-not-displaying-results-according-to-input

Comment: @Nevermore Don't worry, sure. Will have a look.

Comment: @Nevermore Solved. `:D`

Answer (score 2):

You are using jQuery selector for ID (#email1 and #email2) but in HTML there is no id attribute specified but "name". 
Add id attribute and try again.

```
<input class="form-control" id="email1" name="email1" placeholder="Email 1" type="email">
<input class="form-control" id="email2" name="email2" placeholder="Email 2" type="email">
```

Answer (score 1):

As the other both answers advise, you are looking for the `Id` in your selector. you could add the `Id` or change your selectors to look up the `name` like so:-

```
$.validator.addMethod("email_not_same", function(value, element) {
  return $('[name="email1"]').val() != $('[name="email2"]').val();
}, "Both emails should not be same");
```